# Python terminal on OSX yields errors but code runs fine as a file or in iPython

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I am new to OSX. Have installed homebrewed Python 3.7.4 and tried using it in VS Code. I am pretty sure my code is correct -- it runs with no issues on Windows, in iPython on OSX or as a file (i.e., as python file.py).

But when I try using "Run selection/file in Python terminal" function of VS Code the output is a complete mess with repeating code and  errors (mostly IndentationError) all over the place.

Perhaps someone has seen this issue before? Please help!

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from os import chdir, listdir
from os.path import dirname, realpath

try:
    path = dirname(realpath(__file__))
except NameError:
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/project'

chdir(path)

origDF = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'date': ['june', 'july', 'august'], 'A_1': [1,2,3], 'L_1': [2,2,2], 
                        'TA': [1,1,1], 'TL': [2,2,2]})


dataDF = origDF.copy()


def test_equality(dataframe, item1, item2, threshold):
    tmpDF = dataframe.copy()
    tmpDF.loc[:, 'diff'] = abs(tmpDF[item1]/tmpDF[item2] - 1)

    print('\nComparison of {i1} and {i2} with threshold {t}:\n'.format(
        i1=item1, i2=item2, t=threshold))
    print(tmpDF.loc[tmpDF['diff'] > threshold,
                    ['name', 'date', item1, item2]])


# are totals equal?
for s in ['A', 'L']:
    dataDF.loc[:, 'T{}_calc'.format(s)] = dataDF.loc[:, ['{}_'.format(s) in c and not any(
        m in c for m in ['A_6', 'L_8']) for c in dataDF]].sum(axis=1, min_count=1)

test_equality(dataDF, 'TA_calc', 'TL_calc', 0.01)

# are totals equal to the stated totals?
for s in ['A', 'L']:
    test_equality(dataDF, 'T{}'.format(s), 'T{}_calc'.format(s), 0.01)
```

Comment: VS Code might not be using the version you installed with homebrew, it might be using the version that came with the OS.

Comment: Check the VS Code preferences to see if there's a way to specify the location of the python executable, and point it to where brew installed it (it might be `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/local/bin`).

Comment: @Barmar VS Code is using the correct executable -- checked it before. Tried inserting "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python" into settings.json manually -- doesn't help.